# Can we say Cloud Firestore a web server?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have done angular project using cloud firestore as my database for my school and I need to mention which server I have used in this project.

Comment: This question is really too vague to be answered. Technically Firestore isn't a [Web Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) as defined on the wiki, and in general. However, it all depends on how you frame what you say - a web server could be *software* and 'software' is pretty open ended so Firestore could be included as *part* of a web server *solution*. In other words is not the web server, but it could supply data TO a web server. If course your question title states *web server* but your question states *database* so it's just too vague. Just my .02 and IMO.

Answer (score 0):

As said on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ is a database so it is incorrect to call it a web server. Anyway you should point that you used this technology, but as a cloud database.

> Cloud Firestore is a flexible, scalable **database** for mobile, web, and
>   server development

Answer (score 0):

For "school" project and minimal architecture, you can use cloud firestore as your primary database. You can access database directly from your native or hybrid app.

If you want to build a web server, then I think Cloud Functions should be better answer.